# Difference between API-First and Design-API-First approach?

Tags: api, api-design

When I am looking into approach's used for the development of API's, I came across multiple approaches like Code-First, API-First, Design-API-First.

I clearly understand Code-First approach how it is different from other two. But I am not able to get the exact difference between `API-First and Design-First` approach.

**Summary from links:**

**API First:**

1. API's are considered as first class citizens by the organization.
2. You design each of your APIs around a contract written in an API
   description language like Open API for consistency, reusability, and broad
   interoperability.

**Design-API-First:**

1. Describing every API design in an iterative way that both humans and computers can understand before you write any code.
2. API design-first is about the process of creating the API itself.
3. In design API first approach there will be lot of collaboration in designing of the API.

**My understanding by far:**

1. I feel 1 and 2 points of Design-API-First is saying same thing as API First because for example Open API specification is understood by both humans and computers. Is there anything more to it?
2. So, the only difference there will be collaboration added here by involving stakeholders, developers, customers etc?
3. So, when we use Design API First, we can say we are also using API-First?

**References:**

Probably I am able to get the exact context from the following links,
please use them and see if you can get the right understand of it and
address this question.

1. https://blog.stoplight.io/api-first-vs.-api-design-first-a-comprehensive-guide
2. https://blog.axway.com/product-insights/amplify-platform/application-integration/api-first-design-api-first
3. https://www.ecosmob.com/design-first-or-api-first-where-does-future-lies/

Comment: have you read this article https://blog.stoplight.io/how-to-bring-design-first-apis-to-your-organization by the same author? This article explains the additional pieces (Consistency through Design Style Guide, Visual Editors to involve non-tech stakeholders, automated design review, etc.) that need to be achieved for the "Design-API-First" approach?